# Playwright/PyTest - Using Page Objects as Fixtures

Tags: python, automation, pytest, ui-automation, playwright-python

I'm building an automation project using Playwright and Python.

This is the basic structure of my project:
[image]

I'm wondering about the best practice of using pytest fixtures in order to initialize my page objects, so I'll have to do it only once, and then only to call the fixtures in the relevant tests.

This is my test_login.py file:

```
import pytest
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from ...infra.page_objects.login.login_page import LoginPage

@pytest.fixture
async def browser():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch()
        yield browser
        await browser.close()

@pytest.fixture
async def login_page_fixture(browser):
    page = await browser.new_page()
    print("page created")
    login_page = LoginPage(page)
    print("login_page created")
    yield login_page
    await page.close()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_login_with_valid_credentials(login_page_fixture):
    login_page = await login_page_fixture
    print(f"login page url: {login_page.url}")
```

and this is my login_page.py file:

```
from playwright.async_api import Page, expect

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        self.page = page
        self.url = 'https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login'
        self.header = page.locator(".orangehrm-login-branding")
        self.header_logo = page.get_by_role("img", name="company-branding")
        self.username_field = page.get_by_placeholder("Username")
        self.password_field = page.get_by_placeholder("Password")
        self.login_button = page.get_by_role("button", name="Login")
        self.forgot_password_link = page.get_by_text("Forgot your password?")
      
    async def goto(self) :
        await self.page.goto(self.url)
    
    async def verify_page_loaded(self) :
        await expect(self.header).to_be_visible()
        await expect(self.login_title).to_be_visible()

    async def login(self, username: str, password: str) :
        await self.fill_username(username)
        await self.fill_password(password)
        await self.click_login_button()

    async def fill_username(self, username:str) :
        await self.username_field.fill(username)
    
    async def fill_password(self, password: str) :
        await self.password_field.fill(password)

    async def click_login_button(self) :
        await self.login_button.click()
    
    async def click_forgot_password(self) :
        await self.forgot_password_link.click()
```

When I run the test using this command `pytest test_login.py` I get this error message:

```
> login_page_fixture = <coroutine object login_page_fixture at 0x1065db680>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_login_with_valid_credentials(login_page_fixture):
>       print(f"login page url: {login_page_fixture.url}")
E       AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'url'

test_login2.py:22: AttributeError
================================================================================= short test summary info =================================================================================
FAILED test_login2.py::test_login_with_valid_credentials - AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'url'
==================================================================================== 1 failed in 0.05s ====================================================================================
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'login_page_fixture' was never awaited
```

What is the right solution and the best practice for this?